# On Mac Big Sur, what's the correct way to build Python 3.9 with SSL support?

Tags: macos, python, ssl, openssh, python3

I'm using Mac Big Sur.  I want to build Python with SSL support from the binary, whcih I downloaded from here -- https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.9.0/Python-3.9.0.tgz.  Following the instructions here -- https://techglimpse.com/install-python-openssl-support-tutorial/ , I attempted to configure Python with openssl support ...

```
localhost:Python-3.9.0 davea$ ./configure --openssldir="/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1"
configure: error: unrecognized option: `--openssldir=/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1'
Try `./configure --help' for more information
```

The directive is directly from the docs, or so I thought.  What's the proper way to configure Python 3.9 specifying openssl?

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36774171/how-to-include-ssl-with-python-build-on-macos) from StackOverflow?

Comment: That answer is for Python 2.7, no?

Comment: DOUGH!  You are right.  It is quite possilble that the instructions are the same but.. DOUGH! .. :(

Comment: Did you type `configure --help` to see the options?